# Angular 15 With @abacritt/angularx-social-login sign in with google popup opens automatically

Tags: angular, google-signin

I'm building an Angular 15 app with a sign-in with a google option.

Unfortunately on the page where I have integrated the sign-in with google, a pop-up to choose what account to pick keeps automatically opening upon page initiation

This window:

[image]

Here is the declaration of the package:

```
    {
  provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
  useValue: {
    autoLogin: false,
    providers: [
      {
        id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
          environment.googleLoginKey
        )
      },
      {
        id: FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        provider: new FacebookLoginProvider(
          environment.facebookLoginKey
        )
      }
    ],
    onError: (err) => {
      console.error(err);
    }
  } as SocialAuthServiceConfig
}
```

Here is the login function

```
  this._externalAuthService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
  this.user = user;
  this.loggedIn = (user != null);
});
```

The expected behavior: is that the pop-up will appear only when I click the button that calls the login function

I have tried adding autoLogin: false in the declaration of the package but it didn't help

Does anyone know what causes the window to open automatically instead of on command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
  provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
  useValue: {
    autoLogin: false,
    providers: [
      {
        id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
          'clientId',
          {
            oneTapEnabled: false, // <===== default is true
          }
        )
      },
    ],
    onError: (err) => {
      console.error(err);
    }
  } as SocialAuthServiceConfig,
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: {oneTapEnabled: false} worked for me. Now not showing a prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I would try Vladimir's suggestion about oneTapEnabled first. but for me I had the following code code in the ngOnInit() method, and it popped up the login page on load. I fixed it by moving it to the click method.

```
this.googleAuthService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
  var socialUser = user;
  var isLoggedIn = (user != null);
});
```